# Touchscreen calibration on android

Tags: android, touchscreen

I've an android TV box (jellybean) to which I have connected a 17'' eGalaxy touchscreen. It moves the pointer but only with in a small are. I've created the necessary idc file but don't know the right configuration to put in it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to run a touch screen calibration app.

Regards
Rasmus